# Worklight custom loggers

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst

For an audit purpose I want to log in to a different log file other than the existing log files such as info, debug, error, warn. My new log file name would be AUDIT.log and I want to write a statement as WL.Logger.audit('...') to redirect to the new log file. Please suggest how can I do it.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is create a Javascript adapter which will use Java code. It is pretty simple to set up.

First create a Javascript adapter to upload your client logs to. You can follow the instructions from the Server Preparation document in Knowledge Center.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_uploaded_client_log_data.html?lang=en

Then create a Java class under the `server/lib` folder. I created the class `LogDownloader.java` under the package `com.sample.customcode`.

Inside the `LogDownloader.java`

```
package com.sample.customcode;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LogDownloader {
    public static void download(String deviceInfo, String logMessages) throws IOException {
        //Create a new file
        File file = new File("audit.log");

        //Create the file writer
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        //Write to the file
        writer.write(deviceInfo + "\n");
        writer.write(logMessages + "\n");

        //Close the stream
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }
}
```

Inside my `WLClientLogReceiver` adapter I can use my Java calls and call it with the parameters I want. Like below:

```
function log(deviceInfo, logMessages) {
    com.sample.customcode.LogDownloader.download(JSON.stringify(deviceInfo), JSON.stringify(logMessages));
    return {
        result: true
    };

}
```

On the server side you can pars how you want to when writing to your log file. You have the option to parse the JSON inside your Javascript adapter or Parse inside your Java Class.

If I wanted to log specific messages in my file then on the client side I would create a logger package

`var audit = WL.Logger.create({pkg: "AUDIT"});`

Now that I have a logger package I can call:

`audit.debug("DEBUG");`

`audit.info("INFO");`

`audit.error("ERROR");`

When parsing the client logs on the server side I would only forward logs with the package name `audit` to the new server log file.

The new log file will be created at the root level of your server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API as WL.Logger.audit(), however you can create your own logger package to make the differentiation you're looking for. See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/apiref/c_configuring_logger.html?lang=en

See here for a fuller example code: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/apiref/r_logger_js_module_example.html?lang=en